# Editar campos de formulario en Django para modificar el objeto input

Tags: javascript, python, django, formularios

Necesito validar un formulario, pero Foundation Abide PlugIn funciona seleccionado los campos `input` que tiene añadida la etiqueta `required`:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="1234" aria-describedby="exampleHelpText" required pattern="number">
```

Como verán, Django no imprime en pantalla los campos input con etiquetas adicionales, imprime el nombre, el tipo y el id, pero no agrega al final la etiqueda `required`.

Tengo dos formularios, el básico generado por WagtailCMS, y uno personalizado que tengo:

```
class AffiliationInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Affiliation
        fields = ['person', 'affiliation', ]


class AffiliatesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Affiliates
        fields = '__all__'
```

No agrego nada por acá e imprimo manualmente cada campo del formulario de esta manera:

```
{% for field in form %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                    <label for="middle-label id_{{ field.name }}" class="text-right middle">
                        {% if field.field.required %}<span class="required">{{ field.label }}</span>
                        {% else %}
                            {{ field.label }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                    {{ field }}
                    {% if field.help_text %}
                    <label for="id_{{ field.name }}_helptext" class="help-text">{{ field.help_text }}</label>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

¿De qué manera se puede editar el campo para que incluya esta etiqueta y así validar correctamente el formulario?

**Actualización:**
He logrado que la etiqueta `input` tenga el atributo requerido, pero quiero condicionar la etiqueta a todos los campos que no pueden ser nulos, tal como lo hace el admin, es posible hacer esto, por ejemplo, con un condicional?

Y segundo, en el formulario actual no reconoce que `{% form.field.required %}` sea verdadero, por lo cuál no agrega el `*` al final de la etiqueta `label`, que puede estar sucediendo?

**Actualización:**
He conseguido agregarle el atributo `required` al objeto `input` de forma dinámica obteniendo los campos requeridos con python de la siguiente manera:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AffiliatesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        model_fields = self.Meta.model._meta.get_fields()
        model_fields_names = []
        for model_field in model_fields:
            if not model_field.null:
                model_fields_names.append(model_field.name)

        x = model_fields_names.index('id')
        model_fields_names.pop(x)

        # model_fields_names = [f.name for f in model_fields]
        # print(model_fields_names)
        for field in model_fields_names:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs = {
                'required': True
            }
```

Es una manera rústica nada elegante, por lo cuál quisiera saber como depurarlo de una mejor manera.

Sigo a la espera de poner a los campos de formulario el atributo `required` ya que la plantilla no encuentra que sea cierto `field.required` por lo cuál no me agrega los `*`.

**Actualización:**
Perfecto, todo solucionado.

Resulta que al verificar si el campo era requerido, es necesario poner field para en la plantilla:

```
{% if form.position.field.required %}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes actualizar tu pregunta para mostrar cómo generas tu formulario? Puede ser el archivo `forms.py` aunque también podría ser `views.py`. Edito: no aclaras que es _Abide_, tal vez supongas que todo sabemos que es, pero es mejor que no hagas tales suposiciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es muy sencillo de lograr, solo tienes que sobreescribir el método `__init__` de tu formulario y actualizar los atributos del campo.

Te dejo un ejemplo usando tu formulario `AffiliatesForm`:

```
class AffiliatesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AffiliatesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Agregar el atributo 'required' al campo name
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs = {
            'required': True
        }

    class Meta:
        model = Affiliates
        fields = [
            'name', 
            # Los demás campos
            '...', 
        ]
```

De hecho, puedes agregar los atributos que quieras, ejemplo con un formulario cualquiera:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['campo1'].widget.attrs = {
            'required': True
            'placeholder': 'Ejemplo de placeholder'
        }
        self.fields['campo2'].widget.attrs = {
            'required': True
            'data-bar': 'Algo aquí'
        }
        self.fields['campo3'].widget.attrs = {
            'disabled': True,
            'data-foo': 'Algo más por aquí'
        }

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [
            'campo1', 
            'campo2',
            'campo3'
        ]
```

Yo, por ejemplo uso Bootstrap y necesito que todos mis inputs contengan la clase `form-control`, si tengo muchos campos sería una locura hacerlo uno por uno, pero puedes hacer algo así:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs = {
                'class': 'form-control'
            }

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [
            'campo1', 
            '...',
            'campo99999999'
        ]
```

Comment: con eso puedo lograr que al imprimir la etiqueta `input` venga con el atributo `required`??
Por que todos los campos están requeridos ya, los que se necesitan, y lo sé por que la etiqueta `span` se imprime siempre que el campo sea requerido con un * como contenido. Si no me hecho entender, quiero que se imprima así: `<input ... required>`

Comment: @SalahAdDin no entiendo muy bien, pero me parece que Django no agregar el atributo `required` a los inputs ya que las validaciones de los campos requeridos la hace de distinta forma. Puedes probar inspeccionando el elemento

Comment: No entiendo, en el formulario normal no vienen por defecto los campos requeridos? Por qué en el administrador si nos muestran que campos son requeridos?

Comment: Amigo, te voy a dar chulito a la respuesta por que sí, efectivamente si agrega la etiqueta `required` al `input`.

Pero, me surge otra pregunta relacionada, voy a editar para agregar esa pregunta.